# How to map a list to integers

Tags: python, string, list

I have a concatenated string, joined by a comma. I need to split this list into a list, but the type of the list must strictly by integers.

`doc[column] = map(int, [v for v in value.split(',') if v and len(v)])`

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I thought adding `if v` and then perhaps `len(v)` would resolve the problem. How should I do this?

Comment: change `if v and len(v)` to `if v.strip()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the strings are digit-only. You can use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
doc[column] = [int(v) for v in value.split(',') if v.strip().isdigit()]
```

NOTE: Above will not accept negative integer. To handle it, you need more conditions.

**UPDATE**

updated the answer to handle `' 1'` case:

```
>>> int(' 1')
1
>>> ' 1'.isdigit()
False
>>> ' 1'.strip().isdigit()
True
```

**UPDATE** according to OP's comment:

To be complete, you need to try `float`/`int` to see whether the value is convertable to the type.

Example:

```
def try_float(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return False

value = '1, 2.3, 4, 5, blah, 6.78'
numbers = [float(x) for x in value.split(',') if try_float(x)]
```

Comment: @behzad.nouri, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer to use `str.strip` to handle that case.

Comment: Thanks, I thought isdigit is for char only, my bad. I need to do this as well for floats, but I realized `isdigit` won't work then. Any clue to handle that case?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie, How about this? http://ideone.com/n7JnXo (Try `float` and catch exception in a custom function)

Answer (score 1):

Make a nicely named function:

```
def converts_to_int(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

It's shorter to use a list comprehension than use map:

```
doc[column] = [int(v) for v in value.split(',') if converts_to_int(v)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but `isdigit` works fine for integers. I noticed however I'll need to do this for floats.

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie `isdigit` works fine if you remove spaces, and your integers are positive.